# Rhino Mocks - MethodInvocation.ReturnValue vs IMethodOptions.Return

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

Playing around with Rhino Mocks, i just stumbled upon a strange behaviour, which I cannot understand.

Setting up my Stub the following way works as expected - 42 is returned

```
var generator = MockRepository.GenerateStub<INumberGenerator>();
generator.Stub(x => x.GetNumber()).Return(42);
```

Then I tried using the `WhenCalled(Action<MethodInvocation> action)` extension, which I used so far only for void functions:

```
generator.Stub(x => x.GetNumber()).WhenCalled(mi => mi.ReturnValue = 42);
```

This code throws me an exception `Method 'INumberGenerator.GetNumber();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.`. Ok, I've added `.Return(55)` - and now things start to get weird:

```
generator.Stub(x => x.GetNumber()).WhenCalled(mi => mi.ReturnValue = 42).Return(55);
```

Which now returns **42**, instead of **55**. Note that the `MethodInvocation.ReturnValue` *only* works when adding the `.Return(..)` statement which then has absolutely no effect on the returnvalue - which confuses me a lot. Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

Rhino Mocks requires you to specify a `Return()` call at the end of an `Expect()` chain (in your case, when you're setting expectation for your stub), so that it can determine the **type of the return result**.

So, in effect, the return value in `WhenCalled()` is only used. Any value in `Returns()` would do (and not be used) as long as it is of the same type.

Not explicitly mentioned in the documentation I think.

Comment: Exactly. I always write it like this: `.Stub(...).WhenCalled(...) /* make Rhino happy */.Return(0)` (in multiple lines, which is not possible in a comment here.)

Comment: /*make Rhino Happy*/ was a damn Punch-line for sure! Sums up the hassles of Rhino mocks ... hence MoQ ;)

Comment: I think it is not too bad. WhenCalled is used very rare. For the "normal" usage it is important to have some validation. In this case, Rhino doesn't know that you already specified a return value in WhenCalled. Ok, probably it could assume it.

Comment: Don't want to get into other things, but in this case too 'ReturnValue' should be good enough for Rhino, don't you think?

Comment: Rhino Mocks is not that bad - unfortunatelly, it seems like that nobody cleaned up some old stuff when working on the code. :/ I just tried MoQ - it is good (no question), but what makes it better than Rhino? Maybe I need to reopen another question.. :)